# MySQL #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Обращаюсь к базе с запросом

```
UPDATE `departure`
        SET `register_pay_id` = '77'
        WHERE `author` = '15'
        AND `register_pay_id` = 'without_register_pay'
        AND `akt_id` = 'without_act'
        AND `status_code` = 4
```

Обратно получаю ответ

```
Ошибка
SQL запрос:


UPDATE `departure`
            SET `register_pay_id` = '77'
            WHERE `author` = '15'
            AND `register_pay_id` = 'without_register_pay'
            AND `akt_id` = 'without_act'
            AND `status_code` = 4
Ответ MySQL: Документация

#1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'ERR_INVALID_DISPATCHNUMBER'
```

Не пойму в чем причина, может по тому что в set и в where присутствуют одинаковые названия полей `register_pay_id`? Как это возможно решить?

для инфо в `register_pay_id` значения varchar(255)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это сообщение означает, что вы пытаетесь сравнить число и строку в предложении WHERE.

Хранить строки и числа в одних полях плохая практика.
По хорошему у всех ваших полей должен быть тип `int`.
И вместо значений `without_register_pay` и `without_act` должен быть `NULL`.

Так же, чтобы убрать ошибку, вы можете отключить строгий режим для MySQL убрав значение `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` для настройки `sql_mode` в конфигурационном файле `my.cnf`.

Answer (score -2):

```
        UPDATE `departure`
        SET `register_pay_id` = '77'
        WHERE `author` = '15'
        ,`register_pay_id` = 'without_register_pay'
        ,`akt_id` = 'without_act'
        ,`status_code` = 4
```

***AND*** исправь на ***,***  ты же ***SET*** делаешь

Comment: Вы уверены, что это будет где-то работать? Если не совсем, то удалите пожалуйста ответ.